# Is it possible to pass 2 variables to a view in View Composers?

Tags: laravel, variables

I am trying to pass 2 variables to View Composers like this:

```
public function compose(View $view)
  {
      $catalog = Category::with('children')->where('parent_id', NULL)->get();
      //
      if(isset($catalog->img)){
        // $cat = Category::
        $contents = collect(Storage::disk('google')->listContents('sdfJSALSNldKdnslwk230jsd/', false));
        $file = $contents
        ->where('type', '=', 'file')
        ->where('filename', '=', pathinfo($catalog->img, PATHINFO_FILENAME))
        ->where('extension', '=', pathinfo($catalog->img, PATHINFO_EXTENSION))
        ->first();
      $catimg = isset($file['path'])?(Storage::disk('google')->exists($file['path'])?Storage::disk('google')->url($file['path']):NULL):NULL;
      };
      //
      return $view->with(['catalog' => $catalog, 'catimg' => $catimg]);
  }
```

But I am getting the error: `Undefined variable $catimg`.

Perhaps this is not the correct method for passing the second variable?

And also, at the top I check if the image exists in the database, but it seems to me that this is the wrong way, since only parent elements are returned there, how can I check if there is an image for each category? Probably need to run through foreach?

```
@foreach( $catalog as $item )
  <li class='has-sub'><a href="#"><img class="catalogimg" src="@isset($item->img){{Storage::url($catimg)}}@else /img/categories/kitchen-utensils.png @endisset"><span class="cat-text">{{ $item->name }}</span></a>
    <ul>
      @foreach( $item->children as $subitem )
        <li><a href='/{{ $item->url }}/{{ $subitem->url }}'><img class="catalogimg" src="@isset($subitem->img){{Storage::url($catimg)}}@else /img/categories/kitchen-utensils.png @endisset"><span class="cat-text">{{ $subitem->name }}</span></a></li>
      @endforeach
    </ul>
  </li>
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the variables correctly!

The problem is that you defined `$catimg` only inside your `if-structure`.
You will have to think about the case when `isset($catalog->img)` is `false`.

In this case no image is present for the category and the `if-structure` won't be entered and therefore `$catimg` is not defined. So you will either have to check in your view file if $cat_img is set, return a default image or disallow this action. (Or only allow categories with images).

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Yes, I figured it out too. Here in my Google Drive images for each category will be stored, and now I want to get a image for each, for this there is this piece of code with `$catimg`, will it work? I added a view to the main question.